Subequations with the sub-labels and the main label present
I am using the subequations environment (and the align environment) so that my system of equations has a label for each of its equations.
However, I would like to also have the main label appearing, either as:

the sub-label is at the left of the respective equation and the main label at the right of the system;
or
the sub-label is at the right of the respective equation and the main label is at the right of the sub-labels (with, for example, braces).

I give an example of my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:1}
\begin{align}
x&=a+b\label{sub_eq:1}\\
y&=c+d\label{sub_eq:2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Welcome! You likely want \label{eq:1} just after \begin{subequations}, not inside align. Anyway, I don't think adding a useless tag is helpful to the readers: subequations is enough to tell them that the equations form a group.

@egreg Oh, you're right! I have edited the question and put the label in the right place. Thank you! It's more about aesthetics really... How would you prefer: with the main label or without? Do you think with the main label it becomes "too much information"?

I would prefer without the main label. It is pretty clear that (1a) and (1b) are two items in the group (1) of equations.

@WillieWong Thanks for sharing your opinion! I'll follow your advice and leave it as it is.
